# Is it safe to write password in signing configuration?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Is it safe to write Key Password and Store Password in signing configuration in Project structure?

[image]

Comment: Depends who has access to your computer; or to your project if that's shared.

Comment: @khelwood I mean to export apk file on store or somthing.

Comment: It'll be shown in plaintext inside your build.gradle. It won't end up in the APK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been thinking about that recently and I've figured out better solution. You can put in gradle configuration information from where it should look for signing data. So If You are working with git You can ignore that file. Any new developer after taking the project and willing to sign apk will have to obtain mentioned file before building release.

Here is the example. In gradle file in signingConfigs tag You use `Properties` which is reading `keystore.config` containing signing information:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        Properties keystoreProps = new Properties()
        keystoreProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('keystore.config')))

        keyAlias keystoreProps['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProps['keyPassword']
        storePassword keystoreProps['storePassword']
        storeFile file('keystore.jks')
    }
}
```

Here is the keystore.config file:

```
keyAlias=MyAlias
keyPassword=MyPassword
storePassword=StorePassword
```

The above solution assumes that the `keystore.jks` and `keystore.config` are located in the `app` folder but You are free to change the path.